# What is this component and what function does it serve?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, identification, triac, touch

[image]

I am learning to build a touch switch using a TRIAC. I took apart a commercial switch that is activated by touching the thin white wire.

I identified all the components, except one (the one that I have indicated with an arrow). I have no idea what component it is, it has 4 pins and it is made of a resin that apparently was molded by hand because it has marks of fingerprints.

On the circuit diagram I numbered the pins from left to right and highlighted it with yellow. I have analyzed the circuit but I can't find out what that component is. What is it and what function does it serve?

Comment: My guess would be that it's a custom optoisolator. Pins 2 and 3 connect to an LED, and pins 1 and 4 connect to a photoresistor. This allows a DC control signal from the IC to trigger the triac with an AC signal fed through the gate resistor.

Comment: Optotriac possible.